# JPA. Eclipselink doesn't provide a password for mySQL while it should

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, ejb, eclipselink

I'm trying to use a MySQL database with EclipseLink using Netbeans but I keep getting this EJB-exception when the application is about to get data out of the database:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

As you can see 'using password' is set to NO but this should be YES because I have a password set for accessing the mysql server. I already saved the password in the properties of my server and I can browse through the several databases it contains.

This is my persitence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Project_googlePU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/programmeren_project</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Is there a way of letting EclipseLink provide a password? Or could there be an other problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add user and password to persistence.xml by

```
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value=""/>
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value=""/>
```

By the way you have a JTA Datasource.I think user and password should be in the DS file.

Comment: Thanks alot! I tried this though but then I probably used the wrong name.

Comment: As bilash.saha's mentioned, you are using a datasource so the password is not used.  EclipseLink instead gets a connection from the datasource - the datasource needs to be configured with the password.  The password properties are only used if the Provider is creating the connection instead of using a datasource

Answer (score 2):

I usually supply passwords directly in `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="MYPW"/>
```

Doesn't depend on eclipselink as in bilash.saha's answer.

Comment: well the question was "Is there a way of letting EclipseLink provide a password?"